# Using only 50% of CPU in Acer one 14 Z422

Tags: windows, cpu-usage, bios

[image]

**The above image did not take while running CPU-hungry applications.**

I am using Acer one 14 Z422. I installed Windows 10 pro. Updated to 21H1 update and installed all optional updates. The base frequency of the processor is 2Ghz. But it only utilizes 50% of cpu eve if I running CPU hungry applications. Overall system performance is too low. How can I fix it?

I tried most of the google result advice.

Comment: any energy savings enable? What are the Power settings on Windows? Was the power cable connected? I. e. on my H720 the cpu is limited to 1ghz if I run on battery

Comment: I checked by connecting power and slide the perfomance to the maximum. But no change. I cannot see any fan related settings in bios too, if this is happening by low fan speed.

Comment: did you updated the bios and drivers to the latest version? can you run prime95 on windows and a Linux live CD to verify that the windows is not the fault? ;)

Comment: @djdomi I did not update the BIOS. But installed all Optional updates in the Windows 10 update window. I did not run Prime 95, but I will update the result soon here for both Linux and Windows. I am having Ubuntu Mate on this laptop. And I can see, CPU usage graph in the System monitor going near to 90% for all cores while running CPU hungry tasks. But there is no frequency indicator there like in Windows task manager. So I am doubt about I am seeing the percentage of "0.98Ghz" on the graph. Is there any option to view that?

Comment: Dont think, act :-) on linux just run `watch -n1 "lscpu | grep MHz"`

Comment: I investigate and came to know that it is not os dependent issue. In ubuntu also, it showing 998.05 Mhz  before running prime95. Same in lscpu details too. While running prime95 in all the cores utilizes 50% cpu

Comment: @djdomi I found out the result after many discussions and searching. My laptop needed a battery reset. I did that and working fine for me now. You helped me to deviate to the exact solution. Thank you very much for your great support and cooperation.

Comment: so i could write an answer that your problem was nearly the same as the H720? great :)

Comment: @djdomi you can write like, battery hard reset will resolve. 

For me, I need to open the laptop back panel and remove battery and bios battery for one minute. After removing the battery I pressed the power button for 30 sec(I don't know if it was mandatory). Attach the battery and back panel. Leave the laptop one hour. After one hour I start it and I can see my problem fixed.

Comment: But the boot time is still pathetic. I measure boot to usable desktop time for various os. I got a bad list of time.

(Windows 2.5 min, 
Ubuntu 1.75 min, 
Xubuntu 1.5min, 
Ubuntu Mate 1.5 min, 
Lubuntu 1.25 min)